# Java array vs Array

Tags: java, arrays

It's been a while since I took a proper course on Java and I'm hoping someone can confirm/correct my understanding.

Consider the variables int[] arr and ArrayList arrLi:

1. arr has pointers directly to each component. arr[3] goes directly to the fourth element whereas arrLi.get(3) would have to traverse through the first three elements to get to the fourth.
2. Reassigning a component, such as a[3] = 0, does not rewrite the entire array.
3. Each time you want to add an element to arr, you would need to rewrite the entire array. For example, if there are 100 elements in arr, you have to make a new array with size 101 and copy all the elements from arr then add the new one. If you later decide to add yet another element, you'd have to go through the whole process again to add the 102-nd element.
4. arrLi adds (to end, front, or middle) and removes elements very efficiently because all it does is add/remove nodes and adjust the links.

Comment: I think you've confused an ArrayList with a LinkedList.  An ArrayList has a backing array, so anything true for an array (such as O(1) random access) is also true for an ArrayList.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a *raw* generic, and none of us should be *considering* raw generic classes. Now, if you asked us to consider `ArrayList<Integer>`, we'd be happy to.

Comment: Thanks @azurefrog. I didn't realize that.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, we can call it `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ArrayList is a resizable array implementation of the List interface.  Therefore fetching an element does not require traversing the previous elements.
2. Rewriting a value does not require rewriting the entire array in either case.
3. Yes, an array does need to be recreated if you need more space.
4. While it is called a list, ArrayList internally behaves much more like an array.  ArrayList sometimes needs to be resized, meaning the underlying array needs to be recreated.  However, this happens infrequently enough to not affect the average performance of an ArrayList over an array by much.

Please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html for more information